# Method assertThat has complication error in java project

Tags: java, junit, environment-variables, assert

I am trying to compile a java project. I get the following error from my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.Object;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import java.lang.String;
import org.junit.Test;
public class EnvironmentsTest {

@Test
public void testGetFoobar() throws Exception {
    assertNull(System.getenv("MY_VAR"));

    injectEnvironmentVariable("MY_VAR", "my_var");

    assertThat(System.getenv("MY_VAR"), is("my_var"));
}


cannot find symbol
symbol:   method is(java.lang.String)
location: class EnvironmentsTest
```

Comment: Add `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;`

Comment: @Oleksandr, it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

is is a matcher from Hamcrest. See http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html

Answer (score 0):

import is:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
```

Answer (score 0):

Type is () and press Alt+Enter to click "import static method.."
You can add CoreMatchers.is.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH8o3.png)